# How to setup MySQL tables that contain rows that are references to other tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a game where the user can register, has an inventory and has weapons in that inventory. I want to store this information in my database.

Here is how I have set it up so far:

- My user table contains a UserID column (along with other information).
- My inventory table contains an InventoryID column and a UserID column
  (the UserID corresponds to the owner of the inventory)
- My Weapons table contains an InventoryID column which references the
  Inventory it belongs to.

Is this the standard way of doing things? Can I change my layout and make it simpler? It just seems a little tedious to work with databases like this.

It would be so much easier if my User table had a reference to an inventory entry and that entry had an array of weapons. I've achieved this by storing references to the ID's of each entry but I can't just create a "User" php class (which has a reference to an Inventory object, which has an array of Weapon objects) by running one query to the database.

Maybe there is a framework to achieve this?

Comment: You would have a table of weapons, a table of inventories, and a table which records which weapon belongs to which inventory

Comment: Can User have more than one inventory?

Comment: No a user only has one inventory and an inventory has many weapons

Comment: That's nice. Is that a web based game @Prodingga? Hmm.. if user and inventory is in one to one relationship, put the invetory id in the user table then the weapon table still contains what's in it. What do you say?

Comment: You can Gustek bellow make a great point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What You described is simple one-to-many relationship.

You don't need inventory table.

You need a user table with `userID` as primary key and use it as a foreign key in weapons table.

With help of joins You can use one query to get all records.

Comment: Is there a framework out there that will just package up that data into a class for me? (ie: I would ask for user with a certain ID, and it would spit out a User class that contains an array of Weapons owned by that user)?

Comment: You can use Doctrine or Propel.

Comment: I am so glad you responded with that, I didn't know what to actually search for. Propel looks awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a NoSQL database? :)

Relational databases often require "join" tables as you describe. You can probably accomplish this without a join table if user to inventory is 1:1 - and 1 weapon can only belong to 1 inventory/user - just have weapons store a user ID.

Comment: I am not familiar with NoSQL unfortunately. How is it different?